# Can one trisect $\arccos(6/7)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, geometric-construction, proof-verification

Is this proof correct?

**Proof**: Here $\theta = \arccos(6/7)$. Now to show we can't trisect $\theta$, we show that $\theta/3$ is not constructible by finding the irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$, whose root it is. By the angle tripling formula we have that, $\cos(3\theta)=4\cos^3(\theta)-3\cos(\theta) \Rightarrow $ $\cos(\theta)=4\cos^3(\theta/3)-3\cos(\theta/3)$. Here we see that $\cos(\theta)=6/7$. Thus we have, $6/7=4\cos^3(\theta/3)-3\cos(\theta/3)$. Take $x=\cos(\theta/3)$. So now we have, 
$28x^3-21x-6=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=28x^3-21x-6$ is a polynomial with root $\cos(\theta/3)$. But $f(x)$ is irreducible by Eisensteins Criterion with $p=3$, thus $[\mathbb Q[\cos(\theta/3)]: \mathbb Q]=3$ which is not a power of two.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: I've tried my best to format your post. Please make sure that it matches exactly what you mean. (I also fixed the problem with $\theta$, since you said $\cos \theta = 6/7$ I assumed you meant that $\theta = \arccos 6/7$, but you should be more clear with that.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i mentioned that I didn't know the syntax, so instead of typing theta, I would just use k in place of it. It is edited now.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams, thanks. i did make some changes, but now is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: The root is $\cos(\theta/3)$, not $\theta/3$ itself. +1 to you.

Comment: i fixed it, but thanks